# Store an URL into a response header so I can access it anywhere

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've searched for hours on this one and didn't find a single answer that worked. Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

I visit my index page with a set parameters E.G:

```
http://localhost:51684/Orders/Index?startDate=20%2F05%2F2015&endDate=26%2F05%2F2015
```

Then i click on an order to go to the Edit View:

```
http://localhost:51684/Orders/Edit/1400069
```

I edit some values and i Post: after saving i return to this edit view but my Request.UrlReferrer is: http://localhost:51684/Orders/Edit/1400069 and not the index

A colleague suggested try looking into headers

So I tried doing the following: Add a custom response header at the start so it can be accessed at any time looks something like this:
Code in **global.asax**

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("SavedFilters", "/Orders/Index"); //Standard Value
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```

And when i apply the filters in the **index** page i do this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("SavedFilters", Request.RawUrl);
```

then this happens when I look at the fiddler app:

```
SavedFilters: /?startDate=20%2F05%2F2015&endDate=26%2F05%2F2015
SavedFilters: /Orders/Index
```

I get 2 headers with the exact same name...

I'm kinda clueless on what to do/try next so.. any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: That or pass the Url through the `TempData`

Comment: this doesn't work the way we want it to: if i go the edit view: SavedFilters: /?startDate=20%2F05%2F2015&endDate=26%2F05%2F2015 is gone only the /Orders/Index is there.. 

and I've been advised not to use tempdata

Comment: Using your own kludge for `TempData` is hardly going to be any better than using `TempData`, surely?

Comment: Could you pass the url through to the Edit action using a url parameter?

Comment: That is my last resort, if everything else fails I guess I could do that, it's just not something I prefer to do

Comment: well @JonHanna that is what i've been told, im a college student, I don't have much experience with this matter :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to send a default header value for "SavedFilters" if you're not specifically setting one in the actual response from the individual web call response?

Simple, change your code in **global.asax** to:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("SavedFilters"))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("SavedFilters", "/Orders/Index"); //Standard Value
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```